# Script keep on running for hours and hours

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to count the number of delimiter (semicolon or comma or pipe) in the 2nd and 3rd line of the file. If the count is not matching the file should move to the rejected folder. When the file is in the location "pathname=/opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles/inbox" the script is working fine. But when the file is not in the location the script is keep on running for hours and hours until force abort it. Am I missing something, can you please help.

```
pathname=/opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles/inbox

findresult=$(find $pathname -type f ( -name "messagemulti.csv" -or -name "messagesemi.txt" -or -name "comma2.txt" -or -name "messagepipe.txt" -or -name "tokkalodi.txt" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-LT3213.csv" -or -name "DMC_CASHFLOW248.csv" -or -name "ADMC_EQBASKET-WEIGHTS_52387.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" ))


Count=`sed -n 2p $findresult | tr '[,]' '\n' | tr '[|]' '\n' | tr '[;]' '\n' | wc -l`
Count2=`sed -n 3p $findresult | tr '[,]' '\n' | tr '[|]' '\n' | tr '[;]' '\n' | wc -l`

echo $Count
echo $Count2
#if the delimiter count from the 2nd line and 3rd line doesnt match the    file will move to the rejected folder
if [ $Count != $Count2 ]

 then echo "Mis Match"

 mv $findresult /opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles/reject
 else echo "Match"
 exit
 fi
```

Comment: If `findresult` is empty, sed is just going to be waiting for input from standard input...

Comment: Hi Ravinder, If you could understand my question this is a different question, my find command works perfectly and I dont want to make any changes to it. Only the issue I am facing is when there is no file exist in the inbox location the script is waiting for the input, for which I am tring to find solution. If file doesnt exist the script should exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the result before counting.
I also made some small changes:

```
if [ -n "${findresult}" ]; then
   Count=$(sed -n 2p ${findresult}  | tr ',|;' '\n' | wc -l)
   Count2=$(sed -n 3p ${findresult} | tr ',|;' '\n' | wc -l)
fi
```

Perhaps you want to avoid `wc`:

```
 if [ -n "${findresult}" ]; then
    str1=$(sed -n '2s/[^,|;]//gp' ${findresult})
    str2=$(sed -n '3s/[^,|;]//gp' ${findresult})
 fi
 if [ ${#str1) -ne ${#str2} ]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the /dev/null to your find result:

```
findresult="$(find $pathname -type f ( .... )) /dev/null"
```

so, sed will get additionally something empty to work on instead of waiting for user input